# Problema de matplotlib con la altura de la barra del eje y

Tags: python, matplotlib

Tengo este codigo:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
import numpy as np 

people = ['Scale 1','Scale 2']
y_pos = np.arange(len(people))
y = [35,45]
fig.set_figheight(len(people))
ax.barh(y_pos, y, height=0.3, align='center')
ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(people)
ax.invert_yaxis()  # labels read top-to-bottom
plt.savefig(url_image, dpi=100)
plt.clf()
```

Funciona perfectamente como se muestra a continuación:
[image: Figure with two y scales]

Pero cuando reduzco el numero de escalas (eje y) a uno:

```
people = ['Scale 1']
y = [35]
```

la altura que se indica en la línea
`ax.barh(y_pos, y, height=0.3, align='center')` no funciona:
[image: Image with only one scale]

Alguna idea de cómo solucionarlo para que se muestre como en la primera figura?

Otro ejemplo con más escalas:
[image: Figure with four scales]

Gracias!

Comment: Buenas te encuentras en StackOverflow en Español. Por favor traduce tu pregunta a este idioma para poder ser ayudado! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que, aunque el ancho de esa barra única es de 0.3 como le has pedido, el rango del eje se ha reducido para ajustarse al máximo al ancho de esa barra, por lo que al final la barra ocupa visualmente más.

Se arregla si fijas manualmente el rango del eje Y, entre -0.4 y 0.4 por ejemplo (ya que la barra se pintará centrada en 0). Así:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
import numpy as np 

people = ['Scale 1']
y = [35]
y_pos = np.arange(len(people))
fig.set_figheight(len(people))
ax.barh(y_pos, y, height=0.3, align='center')
ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_ylim((-.4,.4))
ax.set_yticklabels(people)
ax.invert_yaxis()  # labels read top-to-bottom
```

Y obtienes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!!